# What is the best suggested way to amplify the voltage and ampere of a signal coming out of a microcontroller and keep wave form as it is?

Tags: power, avr, amplifier

I am generating semi-pure sine wave voltage signal out of an AVR microcontroller. The thing is I want to amplify this signal (power amplification [voltage and current]) with keeping wave form as source (as it is produced from the AVR pin) considering the best way to do it without damaging the microcontroller
And without that much complexity of the circuit to be designed and implemented. 
The circuit should be supplying about (2500 watt in output [desired output voltage is 220 volts] and the frequency is about 50HZ )
The input is supposed to be varying between (0-5 volts and about 20 milli ampere)
I've seen many designs on the web, mostly about RF amplification circuits.
I need advice about this certain situation mentioned above.
Any help, or reference source or contribution would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you want a "amplifier".  Without knowing the desired output voltage range, available supply voltages, output current capability, efficiency constraints, accuracy requirements, etc, there is little further to say.

Comment: You need to supply much more information so people will know what are you trying to do. You need to state your power sources and load(s) + requirements for voltage and current. Your source is a since-wave you generate using PWM + filtering out the carries freq.? How do you do that?

Comment: Actually the question was about amplifying regardless the output wattage..now specified info is included in the edit thanks so much for mentioning this. I read the FAQ but I am new. Would appreciate it to upvote for the corrections I made.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop the amplifier is required to produce high efficiency with less components and complexity needed

Comment: .. this is actually "build an inverter", isn't it? What power supply do you have available?

Comment: You *still* haven't answered all the questions.  I asked them for a reason, and expect you to answer them whether you see the point to them or not.  If you knew enough to decide what questions are relevant, you wouldn't be here asking for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now that you've specified that you want 220 V at 2.5 kW out, it sheds a whole different light on the question.  A simple opamp isn't going to do it.

What you want is something called a "inverter".  These are devices intended to produce AC power from DC.  Note that somehow you still have to supply DC at over 2.5 kW as input, regardless of what topology you use.  What the available input voltage is will make a significant difference to the topology.

Another thing to look at are high-power class D amplifiers.  At this voltage and power level, inverters and class D amplifiers won't be all that different.  Inverters are for a specific known frequency, so can be more targeted to that frequency, whereas class D amplifiers have to handle a range of frequencies.

Either way, messing with this voltage and power level is NOT for beginners.  If you have to ask here, you should start with something simpler and less dangerous to learn on.  By the time you're ready to take on designing something like this yourself, you won't need to ask here.

Comment: actually the wave was successfully generated. I need to amplify it, not to redesign an inverter circuit. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Billo: You're presupposing a solution. If what you need is a high-power sinewave, starting with a low-power sinewave is not necessarily the best way to go about it. Most inverters synthesize the class-D drive signals for the output stage directly.

Comment: @Dave Tweed . Thank you so much so I guess what I need is a class-D amplifier.

Comment: I actually selected the answer as proven not because it satisfied my question, but because it was the ONLY one. I thank you so much for the effort you made to make my point clear. You've spoken all what I wish to say. I admire you scientifically neutral thinking and deciding about electronics. Again thank you @EM Fields so much

Comment: @Billo: Thank you, as well. :-) Just for your information, if there's a next time, there's no requirement for you to either upvote or accept an answer if you don't want to.